# How to keep a copy of generator like StratifierKfold

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I execute on my notebook this following commands in two different cell:

- `skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 4).split(X,Y)`
- `regrl = LinearRegression()
  mse = np.mean(cross_val_score(regrl, X, Y, cv = skf, scoring = 'mean_squared_error'))`

the first execution of `cross_val_score` proceed without error, but the second try it return :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-de4073ce654d> in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4     mse = np.mean(cross_val_score(regrl, X, Y, cv = skf, scoring = 'mean_squared_error'))
      5 mse

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
    340                                 n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
    341                                 fit_params=fit_params,
--> 342                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    343     return cv_results['test_score']
    344 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score)
    210         train_scores = _aggregate_score_dicts(train_scores)
    211     else:
--> 212         test_scores, fit_times, score_times = zip(*scores)
    213     test_scores = _aggregate_score_dicts(test_scores)
    214 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

If I execute again : `skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 4).split(X,Y)`
error is not returned, the generator `skf` become empty after being used. 
So I would know how get a copy  of a generator .

Because I need to try many modeles in a loop, but currently I have to refresh `skf` for each iteration, and it's take too much time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 4).split(X,Y)
cross_val_score(regrl, X, Y, cv = skf, ...)
```

where skf is a generator as you observed and will only execute once.

You can do this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 4)
cross_val_score(regrl, X, Y, cv = skf, ...)
```

Here `skf` is an `StratifiedKFold` object, not a generator like your code.

`cross_val_score` (In newer versions of scikit-learn > 0.18, from the model_selection package) can automatically call `split()` on the fold iterator with the supplied data (X, y) whenever it is required. So you dont have to execute that explicitly.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with `StratifiedKfold` , impossible to copy it and becom empty after being used

Comment: @lelchim Did you do what I suggested? Remove the `.split(X, y)` from your code

Comment: I just did it and it work well even for stratifiedShuffleSplit ! perfect